# Is this a good practice to have lightweight object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance

I'm a developer for a website and have many pages with list or CRUD

is this a good practice to create a light object for the page list with only the properties needed and create a heavier object with more properties who inherit from this light object for the Create/Update page ?

does affect performance to always use heavy object, even if most properties are null ?

For example :

```
    class CustomerLight
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
        string FirstName { get; set; }
        string FullName { get; set; }

    }

    class Customer : CustomerLight
    {
        string Adress { get; set; }
        string City { get; set; }
        string ZipCode { get; set; }
    }

    class CustomerFull
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
        string FirstName { get; set; }
        string FullName { get; set; }
        string Adress { get; set; }
        string City { get; set; }
        string ZipCode { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This question has many angles that you can approach it from. To start though I don't see any difference between `CustomerFull` and `Customer`. They are the same properties. I suspect that was just for comparision?

Firstly, yes a larger object will always have a performance hit compared to a small object. However, I would venture to guess that your data is not nearly the size it would need to be for you to ever notice it. For ease of use I would continue to use the larger object. If you are extracting this from a DB then it will be much more simple to use the full object in your code.

The second point is that if you are getting a performance hit then you could always run your site on a more powerful machine (scale up) or work with small query sizes (refactor your code).

A third point is that you could break these components into a relational structure to simplify the objects your a working with and allow for better expansion later. I tend to try and think about my objects in terms of how painful will it be to add something like a second address to this customer in the future? So you might have the customer contain a list of addresses. To do this you might take a look at Entity Framework if you intend to link to a DB or just use the following in code.

```
public class Customer {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }
    public List<Address> addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Address {
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }

} 
// Or if 1 to 1 relationship
public class Customer {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }
    public Address address { get; set; }
}

public class Address {
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }

}
```

Hope this helps answer your question.